# gt() table - header color

Tags: r, gt

How do I add color to the header (i.e the column names) of my data frame using the `gt()` function in R

```
gt_Head <-
  gt_Head %>%
  tab_header(
  title = md("**Table of First 10 Observations**")
  )%>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = 0  
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `column_labels.background.color` option (see all options [here](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_options.html)), e.g.

```
library(gt)
head(mtcars, 10) |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_header(
    title = md("**Table of First 10 Observations**")
  ) |> 
  tab_options(column_labels.background.color = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using `exibble` dataset from `gt` package.
As you can find here in the documentation https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_options.html we could use `heading.background.color` argument:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

tab_1 <-
  exibble %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(fctr, date, time, datetime)) %>%
  gt(
    rowname_col = "row",
    groupname_col = "group"
  ) %>%
  tab_options(
    heading.background.color = "#eebf00",
    heading.border.bottom.color = "#eebd00",
    heading.border.bottom.width = "5px",
    heading.border.lr.color = "#aae100",
    heading.border.lr.width = "50px",   #no effect
  ) %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = md("Data listing from **exibble**"),
    subtitle = md("`exibble` is an R dataset")
  ) %>%
  fmt_number(columns = num) %>%
  fmt_currency(columns = currency) %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "Using commas for separators.",
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = num,
      rows = num > 1000
    )
  ) %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "Using commas for separators.",
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = currency,
      rows = currency > 1000
    )
  ) %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "Alphabetical fruit.",
    locations = cells_column_labels(columns = char)
  )

tab_1
```

[image]